# How to customize Windows OS Login, Windows only login in the range of BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy)

Tags: c#, winlogon, gina

I have a bluetooth device (BLE). when windows machine is in range of this device, then windows manual login should work. otherwise it can not login even username and password is okay.

have to customize login mechanism.

Comment: You are asking to develop a whole app here

Comment: Here I am looking, How I can customize Windows Login features and put condition(Check Condition) and prevent user login